# Find the point on an ellipse by angle.

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

How do I find the point on the ellipses at 45'. I found [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html), which answers part of it, but I need to know how to calculate for (x,y) at 45'. I could also use a good explanation for the `t` variable.  Thanks...

```
x = a cos t 
y = b sin t
```

Comment: the "45" is what you would plug in for t

Comment: From the link I provided it says: `But t is not the angle subtended by that point at the center.` confused me on that point.

Comment: okay i totally understand your question now. sorry about that

Comment: No worries!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have  a $\theta$ value which represents the angle you want to find the $(x,y)$ value of the ellipse at. We can represent a line passing through the origin given $\theta$ in the form of $y=mx$, where $m$ is the slope of the line. The slope of the line will simply be $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$, and so the line becomes $y=(\tan\theta$)x.

Note that your parametric equations are $x=a\cos t$,$y=b \sin t$. If you solve for $t$ and substitute, you can get $$(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2=1$$

Now we need to find the intersection of the ellipse and the line by plugging in $y$.
$$(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{x\tan\theta}{b})^2=1\\x^2(1/a^2+\tan^2\theta/b^2)=1\\x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1/a^2+\tan^2\theta/b^2}}\\y=(\tan\theta)(\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1/a^2+\tan^2\theta/b^2}})$$

Note that the $\pm$ depends on what your angle is. If it is $45$ degrees, then you want both $x$ and $y$ to be positive.

Comment: I have to convert that into code...   ...standby and thanks!

Comment: Does this look right? When I see `tan2θ` = `Math.Tan(Math.Pow(angle, 2))`

Comment: @DonA No, you want to square after you find the tangent, so do Math.Pow(Math.Tan(angle),2)

Comment: Sorry that does make sense.

Comment: `x` = `Math.Sqrt(1 / (1 / Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Tan(angle), 2) / Math.Pow(b, 2)))`

Comment: that looks good at first glance

Comment: I am trying to plot the middle of an ellipse on the new coordinates from this equation - starting from (0,0) minus it's diameter, I am not getting the right place yet.

Comment: @DonA What do you get?

Comment: `Width:=100, height:=150,x:=33.97,y:=55.3`

Comment: I am getting closer with yours. The new Ellipse is close, I must need to calculate the (x,y) and the Diameter of this 36 pixel Ellipse on the given point.

Answer (score 0):

On the 45 degree line, $x = y$, so $a \cos t = b \sin t$.

Assuming $b \neq 0$, $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{\sin t}{\cos t} = \tan t$.

So if $\theta = \arctan \dfrac{a}{b}$, $t = \theta$ and $t = \theta + \pi$ both work.

Apply values of $t$ to the parametric equations to get the actual $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: @NovaDevizen, could you expound on you solution?

Comment: Let $\theta = \arctan \dfrac{a}{b}$.  $x = b \sin \theta$.  $y = a \cos \theta$.  That's it.

Comment: I am getting the same answer for both equations. Width:=260,Height:=202,x:=79.76,y:=79.76.

Comment: Function for x - `Dim _angle = Math.Atan(a / b) Return b * Math.Sin(_angle)`

Comment: Function for y - `Dim _angle = Math.Atan(a / b) Return a * Math.Cos(_angle)`